# Can the normal equation be used to optimise the RNN's weights?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, backpropagation

I have made an RNN from scratch in Tensorflow.js. In order to update my weights (without needing to calculate the derivatives), I thought of using the normal equation to find the optimal values for my RNN's weights. Would you recommend this approach and if not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The normal equation can only directly optimise a single layer that connects input and output. There is no equivalent for multiple layers such as those in any neural network architecture.